# Drupal Commerce add to cart is no longer working for anonymous users

Tags: 7, commerce

I just updated to Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.52 and add to cart is no longer working for anonymous users. It shows the success add to cart message but nothing is added to the cart. If I log in it works fine. I’ve tried:

- I checked out and UID 0 is still in the DB
- Disabled honeypot module
- emptied the cache_from table
- enabled “disable SQL rewrite” on the cart view
- check permissions for the anonymous user
- cleared the cache

UPDATED
The order entity is being created but nothing shows in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Commerce Kickstart added these lines to the */profiles/commerce-kickstart/.gitignore* which prevented new files from being added to git and thus not getting pushed to production.

libraries
modules/contrib
themes/contrib

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart/issues/2937535